# Selenium ChromeDriver authentication (with C#)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to automate a simple process for two days now. I started with a web scraper (as I'd just finished a project using that), but quickly found this wasn't a good option. The site I need access to runs some scripts when the form posts, and I can't get it to work with the scraper. So I turned to HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. Whole lot of banging my head against the wall, no dice. So I tried the Selenium ChromeDriver, and so far that's the closest I've come to getting this to work. I need to:

1. Load login page and submit login form (can't send in URL - doesn't work).
2. Load report form page.
3. Change field values.
4. Submit report form.
5. Download CSV response.

Here's my current code:

```
var username = _configuration.GetValue<string>("LoginCreds:username");
var password = _configuration.GetValue<string>("LoginCreds:password"); 
var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\path\to\libs"); 
driver.Url = "https://mydomain.loginpage.com"; 
driver.Navigate(); 
var usernameField = driver.FindElementById("username"); 
usernameField.SendKeys(username); 
var passwordField = driver.FindElementById("password"); 
passwordField.SendKeys(password); 

driver.FindElementById("submit").Submit(); 

// Handle browser version alert. 
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); 
alert.Dismiss(); 
var html = driver.PageSource; 

Console.WriteLine(html); // This is the HTML of the authenticated page - as expected. 
Console.ReadKey(); 

// Load report form page. 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mydomain.reports.com"); 
html = driver.PageSource; 
Console.WriteLine(html); // Now I get the login page HTML - authentication is lost. 
Console.ReadKey();
```

So authentication seems to be working, but it doesn't persist. I need to be able to move about on the site after authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now with the code I posted. Turned out I had multiple windows open, authenticated to that site, so even refreshing the page was posting back to the login page. Turns out that the ChromeDriver did the trick just fine. I was even able to download the CSV file I need, which is dynamically generated, so there isn't a static URL I can map to for downloading. Here's the working code:

```
var username = _configuration.GetValue<string>("LoginCreds:username");
var password = _configuration.GetValue<string>("LoginCreds:password");

var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Users\path\to\download\WorkingDirectory");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("diable-popup-blocking", "true");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\path\to\libs", chromeOptions);

driver.Url = "https://mydomain.loginpage.com";
driver.Navigate();

driver.FindElementById("username").SendKeys(username);
driver.FindElementById("password").SendKeys(password);

driver.FindElementById("submit").Submit();

// Handle browser version alert.
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();

// Load report form page.
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mydomain.reports.com");

driver.FindElementByName("Option1").Click();
driver.FindElementByName("Option2").Click();
driver.FindElementByName("Option3").Click();

driver.FindElementById("submit").Submit();

Thread.Sleep(30000);

driver.Close();
driver.Quit();
```

I wasn't able to find an elegant solution to close the browser and the console when the download completes. There are solutions posted that scan the download director for a completed file, but that was a lot of effort for little yield. Waiting for 30 seconds gives the CSV file plenty of time to download, and the browser/console cleanup isn't time-sensitive.